# How to convert a date formatted (YYMMDD) as string but with 00 days?

Tags: javascript

I have a date formatted as string, eg: 240800. The date format for that string is YYMMDD. With the below code, I can convert the string to date but it doesn't always work in deducting 1 day. I need my output to be a valid date, not with 00 day. So with the date above, it should be converted and formatted to 07/31/2024.

Here's what I got so far.

```
function formatDate(stringDate) {
  var year = stringDate.substring(0,2);
  var month = stringDate.substring(2,4);
  var day = stringDate.substring(4,6);
  
  var date = new Date('20' + year, month, day);
  
  var formattedDate = date.getMonth() + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
  
  console.log(formattedDate);
}
```

Working:

```
"240800" = 7/31/2024
All months from 4 to 12
```

Not Working:

```
"240100" = 0/31/2024 x
"240200" = 1/29/2024 x
"240300" = 2/31/2024 x
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Well that's the code I'm at right now. I am trying to figure out how by default it is deducting 1 day less so I can understand more the possible solution I can make. I'm thinking of using conditional statement to check the day 00, and month 01 and make calculations but maybe a better solution is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the `date` variable parameter in `new Date()` is counted as 0~11, not the general range,1~12.
So the working answer actually is wrong. It seems like being `right` just for July and August have 31 days.
The correct way is to firstly deduct 1 month and then calculate it. After all of the process is done, you can add 1 month in the end.
The below is working codes:

```js
function formatDate(stringDate) {
  var year = stringDate.substring(0,2);

  //deduct 1 month firstly
  var month = Number(stringDate.substring(2,4))-1;
  var day = stringDate.substring(4,6);
  var date = new Date('20' + year, month, day);

  //add 1 month finally
  var formattedDate = date.getMonth()+1 + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
  
  console.log(formattedDate);
}
formatDate('240100');
```

Comment: Thank you for the info regarding the ```new Date```. Now I understand the logic. And thank you as well for the working code.

Answer (score 0):

In python Assuming your string is yymmdd below function should do what you want. I am sure javascript has some module for date handling.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def fd(s):
    d=datetime.strptime(s[:-2],'%y%m')+timedelta(days=int(s[-2:])-1)
    return d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
function formatDate(stringDate) {
  var year = stringDate.substring(0,2);
  var month = stringDate.substring(2,4);
  var day = stringDate.substring(4,6);
   
   var d1;
if (day==="00")
{   
  d1 = new Date(month + '/01/20' + year);
d1.setDate(d1.getDate() -1);
   //console.log("day1" + d1);
 }
else
{
   d1 = new Date('20' + year, month, day);
}
   
  var formattedDate = d1.getMonth() + '/' + d1.getDate() + '/' + d1.getFullYear();
 
  console.log(formattedDate);
}
```

Comment: What is "this"? Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).